# Where can I find these compilers given in the Rich Header of a system BIOS file?

Tags: pe, binary, compilers

I am working on a project which deals with the BIOS file of a well known manufacturer.

I recovered the file from the disk partition which stores and uses the file in case BIOS is corrupted or its integrity check fails, therefore the file is named as `BIOS_PRE.rcv` by the system.

Though the file has extension `.rcv` but it is actually a 32-bits portable executable, while exploring file headers in DIE(Detect it Easy), I found the [Rich Signature](https://github.com/dishather/richprint#what-is-that-rich-header-of-pe-executables) contains a list of compilers.

Except `MASM` which is in the list, I hardly have any hint about `Compiler: Universal Tuple Compiler(19.00.26213)[C++]` and many more in the list. Or if I am getting it wrong - Microsoft has started renaming its compiler toolkit?

- Any official site or details about these compiler are greatly acknowledged.
- I have attached  `BIOS_PRE.rcv` file: [GitHub link](https://github.com/volkovtree/sysbios/releases/download/sysfile1/BIOS_PRE.7z)

*Screenshots:*

[image: Rich Signature List]

[image: File Signature in DIE]

Comment: `We call the BackEnd “UTC”, which stands for “Universal Tuple Compiler”, although this name doesn’t show up in any of the binaries included into Visual Studio.` https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/optimizing-c-code-overview/